# How to use current date in H2 database SQL query

Tags: sql, h2

I need something like

```
select * from tableName where date_column > now()
```

However, `now()` doesn't work in H2. Please advise.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

use `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`

```
select * from tableName where date_column > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()
```

- [CURRENT_TIMESTAMP](http://www.h2database.com/html/functions.html#current_timestamp)

Comment: In h2 my select now() doesn't work but in update tbl set col = now() it works. How does this fit together? Also they list now() as alternative to current_timestamp on http://www.h2database.com/html/functions.html#current_timestamp

Comment: @john-woo what if date_column is of type date, not timestamp? I'm getting `ORA-30088: datetime/interval precision is out of range` in Oracle for `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() - date_column`

Answer (score 16):

IF you want to compare with present date only then use

```
select * from tableName where date_column > CURRENT_DATE()
```

IF you want to compare with present date and time also

```
select * from tableName where date_column > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```