# Use CURRENT_DATE() in @Formula in Oracle and H2

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, h2

My previous question was closed as duplicate

[Use sysdate in @Formula in Oracle and H2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59255430/use-sysdate-in-formula-in-oracle-and-h2)

Proposed solution:

[How to use current date in H2 database SQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14773729/how-to-use-current-date-in-h2-database-sql-query)

I've tried that CURRENT_TIMESTAMP:

```
@Formula("FLOOR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() - last_date)")
private Long daysSinceLastDate;
```

It's working in integration tests with embedded H2 database, but in running application Oracle:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-30088: datetime/interval precision is out of range
```

CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() is not working at all in Oracle, and CURRENT_TIMESTAMP is not working in H2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've ended with adding interceptor in integration tests datasource configuration.

```
@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    vendorAdapter.setDatabase(Database.H2);
    vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(false);
    vendorAdapter.setShowSql(true);

    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceProviderClass(HibernatePersistenceProvider.class);

    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty(Environment.FORMAT_SQL, "false");
    **properties.put(Environment.INTERCEPTOR, hibernateInterceptor());**
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(properties);

    return entityManagerFactoryBean;
}

@Bean
public EmptyInterceptor hibernateInterceptor() {
    return new EmptyInterceptor() {
        @Override
        public String onPrepareStatement(String sql) {
            String query = super.onPrepareStatement(sql);
            query = query.replace("projaudit0_.sysdate", "CURRENT_DATE()");
            return query;
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue within @Where clause. I needed smth like

```
@Entity
@Where(clause = "open_date <= current_date")
public class SomeEntity {

    // omitted

}
```

and as both Oracle and H2 had function with input precision for current_timestamp, this

```
@Entity
@Where(clause = "open_date <= current_timestamp(6)")
public class SomeEntity {

    // omitted

}
```

worked for me. 6 here is the default value, so it's equivalent to `current_timestamp` in Oracle and `current_timestamp()` in H2.

Answer (score 0):

If you can build H2 from the current sources, you can use

```
CAST(CURRENT_DATE - LAST_DATE AS INT)
```

or Oracle-specific

```
FLOOR(SYSDATE - LAST_DATE)
```

from your previous question.

Oracle 18c also accepts both variants.

You can get sources of H2 on the GitHub:

https://github.com/h2database/h2database

Use the `jar` target as described here:

https://h2database.com/html/build.html#building

Don't use the Maven build of H2, it is experimental only.

Comment: Thank you, but I gone for different approach. I will add an answer